# Floating button not viewed properly on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

Actually i'm trying to add a floating button to my website that will be shown only on mobile devices, the problem is that in chrome debug if i set the view to mobile it's shown properly but when i test the website on an iPhone 7 the position and even the view is not as it should be.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
  <a id="floatButton" href="#" class="float d-none">
            <i class="far fa-2x fa-address-book my-float"></i>
  </a>
```

CSS

```
.float{
    z-index:500;
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:40px;
    right:40px;
    background-color:#007bff;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999;
}

.my-float{
    margin-top:13px;
}
```

Chrome:
[image]

iPhone 7
[image]

What should i do to view it properly even on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because of `position: fixed`

A lot of mobile browsers deliberately do not support position:fixed; on the grounds that fixed elements could get in the way on a small screen.

Try using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Oh i'm yet hiding it or showing it throw a JavaScript function, the problem is another as you can see on iPhone the position is wrong and even there is no circle

Comment: Even this solution has no effect, so i just gone by another approach, thank's for your time

Comment: HI @IgorMytyuk, I'm having the same problem as you, how did you fix it?

Comment: @RaphaelLima just changed my UI and didn't used the float button